# delete first 2 columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am using 'nsepython' library to download Nifty index historical data. Below is my code

```
from nsepython import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import logging

start_date = "01-Mar-2021"
end_date = "07-Jan-2024"

a= ['NIFTY 50']
for i in a:
  symbol = i
  data=index_history(symbol,start_date,end_date)
  df_final= pd.DataFrame(data) 
  df_final = df_final.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This code give data is following format:

```
    INDEX_NAME HistoricalDate      OPEN      HIGH       LOW     CLOSE
0     Nifty 50    05 Jan 2024  21705.75   21749.6   21629.2  21710.80
1     Nifty 50    04 Jan 2024   21605.8  21685.65  21564.55  21658.60
```

I want to delete the first columns with values 0,1,2.. etc.

Tried using `df_final = df_final.drop([''], axis=1)`.

But its not working.

Comment: `df = df.iloc[:, 2:]`?

Comment: the first column with no name and value 0, 1, 2 , is still there. I don't think its working

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 2:]` will for sure remove the first two columns. Your example is unclear. What is the output of `df_final_.head().to_dict('tight')` (please [edit] the question to provide this output).